# How to release $Mathematica$ from the $Pre HoldAllComplete lock

Tags: front-end

Not sure if posted before, but I'm asking this question from a *Mathematica* fellow user who tried to load expressions, whose problem soon turned into a prison break game featuring the following code.

```
SetAttributes[hold, HoldAllComplete];
GetOut /: hold[GetOut] := Unset[$Pre];

$Pre = hold;
```

After executing this code, all subsequent evaluations are hold, including the GetOut "key" and the reset expression.

```
GetOut
$Pre = .
```

Are there any ways to unhold subsequent evaluations, in addition to rebooting *Mathematica*?

Comment: Are you looking for a good solution, or the user's physical integrity should be preserved?

Comment: @belisarius Definitely both, if possible. I don't feel like hurting executed evaluations preceeding the lock.

Comment: Good question. I've always just restarted my kernel when I bungle up `$Pre` or `$PreRead`, since I didn't think there was any other way around. Would be interesting if there was...

Comment: @rm-rf It's interesting that once we change HoldAllComplete to Hold, both the original attempts work.

Comment: Ooh... I have a way out. Writing an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's nothing that can break out of a `HoldAllComplete` as long as it has to pass through the kernel. But what if we had a way to bypass the kernel? Hmmm... buttons!

I suggest using the following button as an escape mechanism instead of your `GetOut`:

```
Button["Clear $Pre", Unset[$Pre]]
```

With this, you can clear `$Pre` by simply clicking it — even with the `HoldAllComplete`. It works because the evaluation is done via the Front End and not the kernel, thus bypassing `$Pre`.

Comment: How does the Button function get evaluated? Is it through the Front End?

Comment: @FrenzYDT. Read the last paragraph?